# How to write JavaScript to interact with Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, chat

Now we are developing a Chat Engine which is based on JavaScript and Flash. But, what we get stuck with now is that we cannot find a good JavaScript library to talk with flash. Additionally, we use OpenFire as our Server. Anyone has a good solution to this problem? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[Flash JavaScript Integration Kit](http://osflash.org/projects/flashjs)

Comment: @Mr Smith: Link broken? (Result: This topic does not exist yet)

Comment: Yep, seems they removed the content or the original authors moved it somewhere else. Unfortunately I don't know where. Google?

Answer (score 1):

In the Flex SDK (though it is not dependent on Flex) is the FABridge, the Flex-Ajax Bridge.

You can find it under {SDK_dir}\frameworks\javascript\FABridge

You can read all about it here, although the tutorial is Flex heavy, best to check out the samples provided in the aforementioned directory.

[Adobe Article on FABridge](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/nitobi_demo_02.html)